# jQuery mouseover menu animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I still have a problem to center the background image below the link, mouseleave does not return exactly to the center of a list, need some help here. thanks!

Here the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonelfolmer/DfkL2/13/)

---

I'm doing a simple menu into a list with a animation that follows the cursor on `mouseover`, and returns to the current position on `mouseleave`.

I want to always be below the current position when the page loads, so how do I calculate this in a div with margin 0 auto? Something like this [example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/).

```
/*jQuery*/
$('li').mouseover( function() {    

    var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5;
    var left = $(this).offset().left + ($(this).width() / 2);

    $('#marker').stop().animate( { top: top, left: left  }, 200 );

});

$('li').mouseleave( function() { 

});
```

I hope everything is clear enough for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the current page. Change the mouseleave. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/DfkL2/6/)

HTML

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu1</li>
        <li class="currentpage">Menu2</li>
        <li>Menu3</li>    
        <li>Menu4</li>    
        <li>Menu5</li>        

    </ul>    

    <div id="marker">*</div>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('li').mouseleave( function() { 
    var top = $('.currentpage').offset().top + $(this).height() + 5;
    var left = $('.currentpage').offset().left + ($(this).width() / 2);

    $('#marker').stop().animate( { top: top, left: left  }, 200 );    
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to put the marker on the currentpage link on load?